# Hierarchical data in LINQ and searching

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, hierarchy

I've a data-structure similar to the following:

```
SearchCategories
------------------------------
Id           : int
ParentId     : int (nullable)
Title        : varchar (70)
```

The ParentId is a foreign key back to the Id on the same table, this allows for an infinitely nested hierarchy of search categories.

From there, I have a ContentLinks table:

```
ContentLinks
--------------------------------
Id               : int
SearchCategoryId : int
Title            : varchar (70)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is provide a SearchCategory.Id (that has child SearchCategories) and find all ContentLinks that are in the given search category, and in any of it's children using LINQ to SQL.

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible using linq to sql in some easy way. You can always use sql query to be executed directly ([how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx)). In sql server you can use Common Table Expression (CTE) to  get the data for self join. To get started with CTE you may see [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)